# How long should a 75mb sql file take to import in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm importing a 75mb sql file into MySql using PHPMyAdmin. Specifically, it's the Moby Thesaurus (http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mthes.html).

75MB doesn't seem that much to me, but it's taking literally days to import. Does this sound right?

Comment: Shouldn't take days.

Comment: Shouldn't take that long indeed, at least if you don't run SQL on a 20 years old machine...

Comment: It could depend on a lot of factors: your upload speed, the speed of the hosts network, your `php.ini` configuration and so forth. Personally, I always import my SQL files by command line, should they be larger than about 20 MB.

Comment: @Bartdude - Nope, relatively new!

Comment: Do it on command line `mysql -uUSER -p DBNAME < SQLFILE.SQL` input password when prompted go make a cuppa

Comment: @Dave Hi Dave. This is what we ended up doing, so if you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it on command line:

```
mysql -u USER -p DBNAME < SQLFILE.SQL
```

Enter password when prompted and there you go.

Answer (score 3):

PHPMyAdmin is not the best solution for large imports like that, it loads each row as a separate statement and its import function is best used on smaller data sets such as incremental updates to a table. I'd recommend something more like an ETL software, such as Talend to import your data.

https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio

Comment: Ah, that might explain it then - while the file's not massive, there are millions of rows in it.

Comment: MY IT department ended up importing it from the command prompt.