# Does import resume in phpMyAdmin actually work?

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have nearly newest phpMyAdmin (4.3.11.1). I'm attempting to import (to localhost development environment, so all timeouts set at max or infinite) 30 MB `.sql` file, zipped to 3.2 MB `.sql.zip`.

I have `Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit` option checked by default and willing to use this mechanism.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Selecting a file and uploading it for the first time.
2. Import ends with `Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume` error (?).
3. Clicking on `Go Back`.
4. Selecting *the same file* for second (and so on) time and uploading it again.
5. Import breaks each time on exactly the same line of `.sql` file with exactly the same error.

It takes it around 5-10 mintes to break, so I'm surely far above 30 seconds limits for hostings. But, it is clear for me, that on re-upload or import continue ever happens here.

What am I missing? Is this feature working at all? Does it requires any special settings to be set, some extra tables to be created or anything, that I might unintentionally skipped?

**Edit**: *I, of course, managed to import this data, using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559120/1469208). However, my question is, what am I missing, that import resume does not work in my case, not -- how to import this data.*

Comment: Yes it work. Please check link:- http://www.question-defense.com/2009/06/17/phpmyadmin-script-timeout-passed-if-you-want-to-finish-import-please-resubmit-same-file-and-import-will-resume. Hope you will get some help.

Comment: Nope, your link brings no help to me. Linked article says (in title): "(...) _please resubmit same file and import will resume_". I'm resubmitting the same file and there is no resume. Import always breaks on the same SQL line.